# Unable to use socket.io behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, socket.io

I'm unable to connect to a node js server which is hosted online from behind my corporate proxy.

```
var sock = io.connect("http://example.com/");
```

My proxy settings is

> proxy server = proxy
>
> proxy port = 8080

It works when I bypass the proxy.

How do i make the request through the proxy ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which socket.io version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to that your proxy does not handle websockets. Try to disable websockets in your socket.io configuration (Documentation to be found [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO))

Set

```
io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
```

and try again. Good Luck!